# Trying to get a list of properties dynamically where count > 0

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, model

I have a model like so

```
public class UserModel
{
    List<UserModel> users
}
public class UserModel
{
    public List<UserSomeObj> userSomeObj { get; set; }
    public List<UserSomeOtherObj> userSomeOtherObj { get; set; }
}
public class UserSomeObj
{
    public int someIntProperty { get; set; }
    public string someStringProperty { get; set; }
}
public class UserSomeOtherObj
{
    public int someIntProperty { get; set; }
    public string someStringProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Each UserModel class List is comprised of several other class Lists.

I am referencing them dynamically like so by looping over a list of targeted properties.

to get a list of properties matching the 'prop' variable;

```
var props = MethodToGetTargetedProperties(); 
// props example content would be a list of strings like so "UserSomeObj", "UserSomeOtherObj"
foreach (var prop in props)
{
    var results = users.Select(x => x.GetPropertyValue(prop)).ToList();
    //results contain lists of prop where count == 0 and i dont want them
}
```

what I am trying to do is reduce the results where count of the lists targeted is greater than 0 .... problem is that I can't find the correct order/syntax to get it to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `List<T>` implements the *non-generic* `ICollection` interface, you can cast to that:

```
var results = users.Select(x => x.GetPropertyValue(prop))
                   .Cast<ICollection>()
                   .Where(list => list.Count > 0)
                   .ToList();
```

You could do the cast within the `Where` if you want, although I prefer the above:

```
var results = users.Select(x => x.GetPropertyValue(prop))
                   .Where(list => ((ICollection) list).Count > 0)
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: why not just cast to `ICollection` and check `Count` property? I bet you have a good reason and I am just looking to learn from your answer. Thanks

Comment: @blins: Ah, the non-generic `ICollection`. Yes, I like it. I couldn't use `ICollection<T>` because that's not covariant in `T`, but `List<T>` implements `ICollection` as well... Yes, will edit :)

Comment: After looking at your answer more and trying to understand all its facets, I wondered if I could do it all in one line. The two List classes in UserModel have 2 common properties (idSomething and idSomeOtherThing) and since I will be combining them and doing a Distinct, i thought, hmm, one liner might be possible.

Comment: @user3071434: Well it's hard to say without knowing more about what you're doing... but you could use a `SelectMany` to select multiple properties, and then filter...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ..... in reviewing your reply I was able to do the following

```
var results = users.Select(x => x.GetPropertyValue(prop))
    .Cast<IEnumerable<object>>().Where(y => y.Count() > 0).ToList();
```

Then after looking at your answer more and trying to understand all its facets, I wondered if I could do it all in one line. The two List classes in UserModel have 2 common properties (idSomething and idSomeOtherThing) and since I will be combining them and doing a Distinct, i thought, hmm, one liner might be possible.

Comment: If you cast to `IEnumerable` instead of `ICollection` you should use `.Any()` instead of `.Count() > 0`.